# Помогите с запросом SQL на выборку данных

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Подскажите как написать запрос, для вывода трех наиболее оплачиваемых сотрудника предприятия.
Названия полей и таблиц произвольное, мне нужно понять структуру запроса

Comment: Чётко определите - если 3-й и 4-й по убыванию оплаты имеют одинаковую сумму, кто из них должен быть выведен, по какому критерию или при какой сортировке.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так например:

```
SELECT
  name,
  sum(salary) as total
FROM
 Table
group by name
order by total DESC
limit 3;
```

Comment: Спасибо, скажите для чего вы применили группировку по имени? Это необходимо для функционирования запроса или дополнение? И еще отвлеченный вопрос, есть ли разница между синтаксисом запросов к MySQL и к Oracle? Если да то приведенный вами запрос относится куда?

Comment: Группировка в общем случае: у нас есть более одной строки начисления для менеджера. Данный синтаксис максимально общий.

Comment: Запрос даёт недетерминированный результат. Впрочем, это скорее следствие недоопределённости задания.

Comment: @Akina т.е. Вы можете привести пример данных на которых два последовательных запуска запроса дадут разный результат?

Comment: 5 человек имеют одинаковую, при этом максимальную, зарплату. Запрос вернёт 3 случайных из них.

Comment: @Akina нет. Поскольку в БД данные не хранятся в случайном порядке.

Comment: *в БД данные не хранятся в случайном порядке* Это в общем случае неверно. Таблица в БД - это куча. Даже если имеется физический порядок, задаваемый кластерным индексом. Но главное - документация НЕ УСТАНАВЛИВАЕТ порядок возврата записей в подобном случае. Следовательно, порядок - случаен. И то, что на практике записи возвращаются в некоем вроде бы порядке - тоже случайность. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bcb2a0f460b873eed091a2b396827d1). PS. Детерминированность определяется только данными, но не структурой хранения.

Comment: Даже лучше вот так: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba5d1035c972c99c2fd2d721983aa0f3). Структура хранения и данные на момент выполнения первого и последнего SELECT-запросов полностью совпадают.

Comment: @pekpek вроде бы Oracle 11 не умеет обрабатывать limit.